# Eclipse: Work in a team on a remote server

Tags: java, remote-access, server, eclipse

I am working on a big Java-Project. We are a team of currently 4 developers/designers. We all use Eclipse
Now we want to work server based (on an *Ubuntu 18.04 Server*). Is it possible to have a local workspace and sync files to and from the server.

It must be able to work on 2 computers at 1 file and no delays at saving

We tried:

1. Samba Share(Bad)
2. Remote Project in Eclipse(Worked but no debug, no local work, much issues)

What do you suggest to us?

Thanks, Moritz

## edit: The synchronization must be automatically

Comment: Well, you can certainly synch to version control (on the server). You do use version control, don't you?

Comment: Not yet. I thought about git with gitlab. I will try it

Comment: "We are an team of currently 4 developers" - and you don't use version control?? ***STOP*** whatever you are doing. I mean ***everything***. No more design, code or test, nothing at all - until you have version control. Please tell me this isn't at work? In any case, even on Open Source, having no version control is unacceptable and highly dangerous. I use it even on my one man hobby projects.

Comment: It is an private test project. Not open Source or anything like that. I will try it

Comment: Lol. That's a slight relief, but with four of you, you ***NEED*** version control. It can double as backups. You can see who changed what. You can compare different version of a file to see what changed, which is ***very*** useful when bug hunting, etc, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We are an team of currently 4 developers" - and you don't use version control??

***STOP*** whatever you are doing. I mean ***everything***. No more design, code or test, nothing at all - until you have version control.

Please tell me this isn't at work? In any case, even on Open Source, having no version control is unacceptable and highly dangerous. I use it even on my one-man hobby projects.

As a bonus, one you have version control, Eclipse will use it to do the synching that you ask for.

So, the answer to your question of how to synch between 4 developers using Eclipse is via version control.

Comment: I got it. Now I use gitlab and egit in eclipse. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: I ma glad to have helped. I can never understand how many developers don't use version control, or don't know how to use a debugger. It saddens me :-(